# How to Remove a row from Table using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular http service to perform a DELEET operation , Its working fine , after deleting the data record I have to remove that row also from table .

Below is my code for all that

```
$scope.DeleteSchedule = function (recordId) {
   var v =$window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');
   if (v == true) {
       var row = '#row' + recordId;
       var table = 'table #tbl_Schedule_Delete tr ' + row;
       $http({
           url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSchedule", "Admin")',
           method: "DELETE",
           params: {
               recordId: recordId
           }
       }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
           alert('Row Deleted Successfully');
           angular.element(document.querySelector(table)).remove();
           //$('table #tbl_Schedule_Delete tr' + row).remove();
       }, function myError(response) {
           $window.alert('Warning! It failed.');
       });
   }
}
```

Refrence to jQuery `remove()` seems to do nothing

> value of variable table will be 'table #tbl_Schedule_Delete tr #row35'

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(table)).remove();
```

I checked console log and there is no error or warning . How to do this in angular JS

**Update 1 :**
Below is Table Mark Up

```
<tr id="row34" role="row" class="odd">
<td id="delete34" class="sorting_1"> 
<a id="deletebtn_34" ng-click="DeleteSchedule('34')"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#e90029"></i></a>
</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>11956</td>
<td>Tota Ram</td>
<td>04-10-2017</td>
<td>02-12-2017</td>
<td>Haryana</td>
<td>Badaun</td>
<td>03-11-2017</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How do you load data to the table? if you load from an array you just need to remove the value from the array and the table will update

Comment: you using `ng-repeat` ? to load the data in table ?

Comment: HTML Mark up for Table is getting returned from MVC Controller through Model Property

Comment: Have you tried with: $(table).remove(); ?

Comment: While this may not fix your problem the use of `querySelector` inside `àngular.element` is redundant, since `angular.element` already queries elements by selector (it's basically equivalent to `$(selector)`). So `angular.element(document.querySelector(table))` could be reduced to `angular.element(table)`

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen , does it depend on version ? angular.element does not seems to work . I am using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: It shouldn't. If you have jquery loaded, `angular.element(selector)` basically acts like an alias to `jQuery(selector)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't delete the row using angular.element but show/hide the row with ng-if of ng-show.

```
<tr id="row34" role="row" class="odd" ng-show="!deleted[34]">
```

in combination with:

after deletion in your controller:

```
scope.deleted[recordId] = true;
```

Comment: That's smart , Perfect with MVC and Less Code

Comment: Small addition: it's better to use ng-if, because your overall pagespeed and responsiveness will be faster.

Comment: Need to add one more thing , to use this approach we need to initialize $scope.deleted=[] in angular js controller , Otherwise it will give error can not set property 'recordId' of undefined cause deleted is not defined as array in controller

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your selection query. The selector

> table #tbl_Schedule_Delete tr #row35

actually matches the following HTML structure:

```
<table>
    <any-element id="#tabl_Schedule_Delete">
        <tr>
            <any-element id="#row35"></any-element>
        </tr>
    </any-element>
</table>
```

As you can see, this doesn't match your HTML structure. This is because your selection query contains a couple of whitespaces when matching elements and ids. This causes it to look for child elements when matching the ids.

To fix it, your selector should instead look like this:

```
var table = 'table#tbl_Schedule_Delete tr' + row; 
// Notice the lack of whitespaces after 'table' and 'tr'
```

---

*Side note: using `document.querySelector()` inside `angular.element()` is redundant. You could simply use `angular.element(table)` since, `angular.element` is equivalant to using `$(selector)` (it's actually exactly the same, in case that you have jquery loaded)*